# Why do i have to accept the Cookie-Question twice?

Tags: php

I have the following code for a simple Cookie notification and if i accept the Cookie notification should vanish. However i have to press the accept button twice and i don't know why?

```
if(isset($_POST['accept'])) //if Cookies are accepted
{
    Cookie::setCookieAccept();
  
    
}
else if(isset($_POST['deny'])) //If Cookies are denied
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}

if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) //Are Cookies accepted?
{
    echo '<div class = "container">
    <div class="alert cookiealert alert-dark alert-dismissible fade show mb-0 pb-0 d-flex justify-content-center " >
        
        <div class = "test">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    Mit Verwendung dieser Website stimmen Sie zu dass wir Cookies bei Ihnen speichern.
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class = "d-flex justify-content-center" "row">
                
                    <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="accept" value="Akzeptieren" data-dismiss="alert&submit"> 
                
                
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deny" value="Ablehnen" data-dismiss="alert&submit">
                    </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>';

}
```

Comment: what is this function doing? `Cookie::setCookieAccept();`

Comment: it is setting a cookie, called cookie to 1 so i can check if cookies are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_COOKIE['cookie']` is available after reload.

So we trick using a temp variable `$accept` and set it to true, if the cookie is set. If the cookie is not already there, we check for acceptance and if it is, we set accept true.

Afterwards we check again for acceptance, and if not show cookie alert, again.

```
$accept = isset($_COOKIE['cookie']);
if(!$accept) {
    if(isset($_POST['accept']))
    {
        Cookie::setCookieAccept();
        $accept = true;
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['deny']))
    {
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
}

if(!$accept)
{
    // not accepted
}
```